# Mysql Search value used to find row

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible for Mysql to return the search value that it used to find the row?

For example I have a database like this:

```
ID | FLIPPERID | PHONENUMBERS                      | POSTERIDS  
1   10001        7003158974,8769873453,9085699812   6477741332,34234324234,5734345,34234
```

I do a query like this. But with hundreds of values:

```
SELECT * FROM `flipperaccounts` 
WHERE `posterids` = 3126764 
   OR `posterids` = 65139757 
   OR `phonenumbers` = 6477741332 
   OR `posterids` = 72345341;
```

Now I'm wondering if there's a way to know which value triggered the row to showup?

Comment: You have 4 columns defined but only data for 3 columns, I take it you left out `ID`?

Comment: Fixed. Question is still the same.

Comment: You don't really need the value which matched, instead you need the column name that matched. This way you can just access the column through your PHP result

Comment: When you think about it, you don't really need to know which `OR` found the row in the database. You're getting all the values anyway, so you can just compare the values that are fetched with the original values you used in your query with a basic PHP comparison to find what values are similar. This would also allow you to see if there was more than one column that the query was matched by.

Comment: I do need the value that matched. Basically I have a list of phone numbers and posterids that correspond to some other data. I need to know if I have already created an account for them in my database or not. This would be very simple to do if I did each value one by one. But doing 100s of queries in a row would put to much stress on my webhost. I know I can do it without knowing the value matched. But it will be a lot more work on the php side of things.

Comment: is this used for tracking? or just to see if they exist? seeing your comment up there *"I need to know if I have already created an account for them in my database or not."*

Comment: This is used for tracking. Basically I get a list of data including phonenumbers and posterids. I want to create a flipperid to keep track of any data with the same phonenumber or posterid. Sorry if this doesn't make a lot of sense. It's a very complicated system I have setup

Comment: Yup it sounds complicated! But does it actually need to be that complicated? My guess based on the fact you store a comma delimited list rather than a parent child set of tables. Probably not if the database design was done properly

Comment: I think it will be best if you place some of your comments in your question in order for others to see what your intentions are, in order to clarify your question. I had a feeling that's what it was about before reading your comment and my asking you, and that took me a minute or so to figure it out ;-) so a quick copy/paste ought to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a direct comparison using a `case/when/then` statement. I've used CONCAT_WS here in the event that there are multiple columns matched, so you can `explode(',', $row['matched_column'])` for your convenience.

```
SELECT 
    ID,FLIPPERID,PHONENUMBERS,POSTERIDS, CONCAT_WS(', ',
        CASE WHEN posterids = 3126764 THEN 'posterids_1',
        CASE WHEN posterids = 65139757 THEN 'posterids_2',
        CASE WHEN phonenumbers = 6477741332 THEN 'phonenumbers',
        CASE WHEN posterids = 72345341 THEN 'posterids_3' ) AS matched_column
    FROM flipperaccounts
```

Then when you get the result back your table will be like:

```
| ID | FLIPPERID | PHONENUMBERS | POSTERIDS | MATCHED_COLUMN |
  "1"   "10001"    "700315894.." "647774..",  "posterids_2"
```

Then you can access it within your loop statement as an index on the row.

```
if(!empty($row['matched_column'])) {
    echo $row['matched_column'];
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any way to tell what part of a complex WHERE clause caused a SELECTion.

Note that OR is associative (rather than commutative), so more than one of your clauses may cause a hit, and so the order is important to your answer — problem is, the query optimizer knows that OR is associative, and so it may arbitrarily change the order of the OR clauses! For example, if one column has a shorter index, the query optimizer might choose to do that first, or it may choose to do PRIMARY or UNIQUE columns first.

So it seems to me that your question in non-deterministic, without returning an array of OR clauses that "hit."

You could do this by using "SELECT COUNT(*)" for each of the OR clauses, which is fairly non-intensive, if the columns are indexed.

Answer (score 0):

I went with RiggsFolly idea of making a child table. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is pretty borderline NAA, it is a response to a comment under the question.  @Riggs should have posted resolving advice as an answer.

Comment: @mickmackusa 7 years ago? For the life of me I have no idea why I posted a silly comment like that other than irony. My excuse, I was new to the site in those days

Comment: Time flies while we're having fun.   Wanna post an answer?  Wanna close it? How to resolve?

Comment: Not sure my Sunday Evening brain in in the right place to even try :) @mickmackusa